# PIR sensor circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, oscilloscope, npn, pir

I am designing a PIR sensor circuit to detect human movement. I am supposed to display movement using an oscilloscope (the response from [this PIR sensor.](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/infrared/datasheet_pir.ashx?la=en))

I have used the following circuit but it does not show any response on the oscilloscope.

Is there anything that I need to add?

[image]

Comment: Please post specifications/datasheet for the PIR Sensor, there are many types.

Comment: It is PIR sensor MURATA IRA-S210ST01

Comment: The common mode input range of the 741 doesn't go down to the negative rail. Trash this design and use at a minimum an LM324. One section to amplify, another to compare.

Comment: With your scope on pin 2 and ground on pin 3 of the PIR. Set the scope to a sensitive setting. Wave something really hot in front, like a soldering iron.

Comment: @Mattman944 could you clarify a bit more for me , so I need a LM324 instead of 741 and should I keep the transistor as a first stage amp or not

Comment: Mandatory read on 741: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Comment: I would not use a transistor. For low-power, <100 kHz, an opamp is almost always a better choice. Note that an LM124, LM224, LM324 are the same, first digit is the temperature range. 1 = Military, 2 = Industrial, 3= Commercial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments the 741 op-amp is not one of the better choices.
Consider using one of the test circuit configurations in the [IRA-S210ST01 datasheet](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/infrared/datasheet_pir.ashx?la=en), these also use an op-amp similar to that recommended in the comments.

For additional info you can refer to this [application sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/440e/0900766b815bf4ed.pdf). The document also includes a prototype starter board that should be available, schematic included.

In your original circuit you are using the transistor as a switch rather than a linear amplifier. If you want to view an amplified analog output try using one of the the circuits in the datasheet or application sheet to start.

Since the [LM224 op-amp (and similar versions)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm224.pdf?ts=1700062142412&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM224) have multiple parts in one package you can implement an analog stage, a filtering stage, and a comparator stage. Below is one of the test circuits from the datasheet.

[image: Test circuit]

(From [Murata datasheet](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/infrared/datasheet_pir.ashx?la=en) Fig. 5)
.

Comment: Thank you it is working perfectly but is there anyway to reduce the SNR

Comment: What is the pictured test circuit supposed to do?

Comment: @cornelius - The circuit above only outputs a buffered analog signal from the sensor. The signal can be further amplified, filtered, and sent to a comparator if needed. For more info see the original question above and the Murata datasheet link just below the circuit.